# Why the difference between the * unpack operator and the tuple conversion function when using itertools?

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

What is wrong with example 3?

```
import itertools
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [3,4]
l3 = [5,6]
```

Example 1, basic - OK

```
p1 = itertools.product(l1,l2,l3)
for c in p1:
    print c
```

(1, 3, 5) (1, 3, 6) (1, 4, 5) (1, 4, 6) (2, 3, 5) (2, 3, 6) (2, 4, 5) (2, 4, 6)

Example 2, using the unpack operator - OK, and better, 
because I don't have to know how many elements in lists

```
lists = [l1,l2,l3]
p2 = itertools.product(*lists)
for c in p2:
    print c
```

(1, 3, 5) (1, 3, 6) (1, 4, 5) (1, 4, 6) (2, 3, 5) (2, 3, 6) (2, 4, 5) (2, 4, 6)

Example 3, my original alternative to example 2, using the tuple conversion function
Not OK. Why?

```
p3 = itertools.product(tuple(lists))
for c in p3:
    print c
```

([1, 2],) ([3, 4],) ([5, 6],)

```
print tuple(lists)
```

([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])

Comment: You are not unpacking anything by passing in a tuple. You are passing in just **one** argument, and that one argument happens to be a tuple. Why did you expect that to be the same thing as the argument unpacking case?

Comment: I had thought that an arument list was equivalent to a tuple. But clearly it isn't.

Comment: Then how would you ever be able to pass a tuple as an argument to a function?

Comment: Yes its obvious now. But the output of `print tuple(lists)` looked the same as the aregument list in example 1.

Comment: You are confusing the call syntax (which uses parentheses) and a tuple object (which also uses parentheses, but is a separate object, not a call).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you see what's going on:

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [3,4]
l3 = [5,6]
lists = [l1,l2,l3]
def showargs(*args):
  for i,v in enumerate(args):
    print "%d: '%s'" % (i, v)

showargs(lists)
# 0: '[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]'
showargs(tuple(lists))
# 0: '([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])'
showargs(*lists)
# 0: '[1, 2]'
# 1: '[3, 4]'
# 2: '[5, 6]'
showargs(*tuple(lists))
# 0: '[1, 2]'
# 1: '[3, 4]'
# 2: '[5, 6]'
```

Comment: Thanks, @will. I've seen quite a few answers here that use copy & paste of raw interpreter output, so I figured that it was an acceptable standard here. But I'm more than happy to use the style of your edit in future if that is preferred.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable yah, but it just looks a little cleaner, and can also be copy pasted straight into text files / an interpretter yourself.

Comment: Good point. I guess I was also trying to give David a hint that testing stuff in the interpreter can be useful. :)